# MenuItem not visible when using android annotations

Tags: android, menuitem, android-annotations

When i run the code , menuItem is not visible.I think i am missing something.
Below is the details of my code.I have referred android annotation documentation for the same.Thanks

build.gradle

```
def AAVersion = '4.3.1'
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}
```

MainAcitivity.java

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.activity_menu)
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

        @OptionsMenuItem(R.id.menuShare)
        MenuItem menuShare;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ProfileListFragment fragment = ProfileListFragment.newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

        @OptionsItem(R.id.menuShare)
        void menuShareClick() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

activity_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@+id/menuShare"
            android:title="@string/share" />
    </menu>
```

I am trying to setup my toolbar in below fragment

```
 @EFragment(R.layout.fragment_profile_list)
public class ProfileListFragment extends BaseFragment {


    @ViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @ViewById
    FloatingActionButton btnFAB;

    public ProfileListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static ProfileListFragment newInstance() {
        ProfileListFragment fragment = new ProfileListFragment_();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @AfterViews
    void afterViews() {
     //((BaseActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //((BaseActivity) getActivity()).setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    }

    @Click(R.id.btnFAB)
    void btnFABClicked() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), CreateProfileActivity_.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

fragment_profile_list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.biodata.activities.fragments.ProfileListFragment">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Should i place the menuItem and toolbar in fragment?
I cannot set the toolbar in fragment aswell.( facing another problem here)
Kindly correct my understanding.

Comment: Your also have to set up your Toolbar (or ActionBar).

Comment: @WonderCsabo I have updated my question. I have MainActivity which contains ProfileListFragment. I am trying to create new Toolbar in every fragment in my App.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the following line in the `Fragment`:

```
@AfterViews
void afterViews() {
    ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Also do not forget to remove it in `onDestroyView`:

```
@Override
void onDestroyView() {
    ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(null);
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```